# Access next item of a range from within a for loop (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a filtered spreadsheet that has no obvious pattern to it. I need to check whether there are two consecutive cells with grey fill (RGB : 191,191,191). When I say consecutive, I mean out of the visible cells, so consecutive doesn't necessarily mean the row numbers will be consecutive. However I'm not sure how to access the next row of the range from inside the for loop. I've copied and pasted a simplified version of my script to aid answers. Thanks

```
Set Rng = Range("A2:A105").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each rowcheck In Rng
    If Cells(rowcheck.Row, "C").Interior.color = RGB(191, 191, 191) And _'
    'The next visible cell also has an rgb value of 191 Then
    blah blah
    End If
Next rowcheck
```

Comment: 2 things: 1. is it possible to use "C" in `Cells()`? (never seen that) and 2. what do you mean with the next visible cell in that comment after the `and` ?

Comment: @Goosebumbs yes it's possible to use column names in `Cells()`

Comment: I'd use another variable to store the *previous* cell and check that in each iteration, rather than trying to check the next one.

Comment: another way would be iterate only visible cells and add them to another collection if their interior.color = gray, and their position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two passes:

1. get the information
2. loop over the information

For example:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim boo() As Boolean, Rng As Range, i As Long, iMax As Long
    Set Rng = Range("A2:A105").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ReDim boo(1 To Rng.Count)

    i = 1
    For Each rowcheck In Rng
        If Cells(rowcheck.Row, "C").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191) Then
            boo(i) = True
        Else
            boo(i) = False
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next rowcheck
    iMax = i - 2

    For i = 1 To iMax
        If boo(i) And boo(i + 1) Then
        'whatever
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man, had to add `rowNum(i) = rowCheck.Row` in the first for loop so I have a row number to reference at the "'whatever" stage, I'm guessing that's the easiest way?
I really would have thought there would have been an easy way to get to say, the 4th element of a range. You can iterate over these with the For Each loop so it confuses me why you can't reference these explicitly.

Comment: @quantum285 It IS difficult to loop thru a disjoint range by *index.*  I usually need **two** passes, although it is distasteful to me.